# ES6 Dynamically Reference Import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I'm importing a few objects that all have the same method. How can I dynamically reference them, say by strings.

For example,

```
import { Foo } from 'path/to/foo';
import { Bar } from 'path/to/bar';
import { Baz } from 'path/to/baz';

const things = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];

things.forEach(thing => {
  thing.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Why not just express them as `const things = [Foo, Bar, Baz]` and call the method that way...? Why have you expressed them as strings here?

Comment: Does it have to be strings?

Comment: Yeah gotta be strings for my purposes

Comment: @charleszardo Why? Can you elaborate on your use case? Are you sure this isn't an XY problem?

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be strings you can do this:

```
import { Foo } from 'path/to/foo';
import { Bar } from 'path/to/bar';
import { Baz } from 'path/to/baz';

const things = {
'Foo': Foo, 'Bar': Bar, 'Baz': Baz
};

Object.keys(things).forEach(key => {
  things[key].doSomething();
});
```

If it doesn't have to be strings, you can simply create an array of your imported Objects

```
import { Foo } from 'path/to/foo';
import { Bar } from 'path/to/bar';
import { Baz } from 'path/to/baz';

const things = [Foo, Bar, Baz];

things.forEach(thing => {
 thing.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I gotta go with your first recommendation. I was hoping there was a slicker way to do this without having to write some sort of mapping like that but maybe there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use string , use as you have imported like this:

```
import { Foo } from 'path/to/foo';
import { Bar } from 'path/to/bar';
import { Baz } from 'path/to/baz';

const things = [Foo, Bar, Baz];

things.forEach(thing => {
 thing.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Problem is they gotta be strings in my case.